# How to get the data from db

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular

I have an API by which i want to display data by certain conditions,here i am getting the details as,

My service Component,

```
    @Injectable()
    export class GetAllList {
    id = localStorage.getItem('social_id')
    private _productUrl =    'http://localhost/a2server/index.php/profile/getProfile/'+this.id;
   constructor(private _http: Http) { }
    getList(): Observable<IDetails[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
    .map((response: Response) => { 
    return <IDetails[]> response.json(); 
    });
      }
         }
```

My Observable,

```
   export interface IDetails{
    profile_id:number;
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    profilename: string;
    phone:string;
    email:string;
    address:string; 
    }
```

I am using these service in my main component as

```
 ngOnInit(){
  this._service.getList()
 .subscribe(details => this.details = details); 
  }
```

This  works  well,if i want to check firstname in console,how would i do that?Is it like these.....

```
ngOnInit(){
  this._service.getList()
 .subscribe(details => this.details = details); 
  console.log(this.details[0].firstname);
  }
```

Can  any one  suggest  help  please......

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Hi micronyks,profile_id:number;
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    profilename: string;
    phone:string;
    email:string;
    address:string;

Comment: The above are the data  i am  getting  from  db,how can  i  see  firstname in  console

Comment: If it's an asynchronous ajax request, then you are trying to log the data before getting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it as suggested below.

```
ngOnInit(){

  this._service.getList().subscribe((data) =>{    
    this.details = data; 

    this.details.forEach((detail)=>{
          console.log(detail.firstname);  
    })

  });

}
```

Comment: Thats good  micronyks,but i am only the the first record name,i want the firstnames of all records

Comment: Oops. Therr was a little mistake in my code. Changed it.

Comment: i had an other doubht,can u see it

Comment: Yes. Tell me. Whats a new doubt?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38608364/how-to-change-the-properties-of-a-button

Answer (score 1):

```js
ngOnInit(){
  this._service.getList().subscribe(details => { 
    this.details = details; 
    for(let detail of this.details) {
       console.log(detail.firstname);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thats good  but i  am   only  the    the  first  record  name,i  want  the  firstnames of  all  records

Comment: You want to print them on console? loop this.details. see my edits.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your console.log in curly braces, like this:

```
    ngOnInit(){
      this._service.getList()
     .subscribe(details => { this.details = details; 
console.log(this.details[0].firstname);
}); }
```

This makes sure that you don't log it to the console unless you have fetched the data.