# How to change the properties of a button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I have a button as

My Template,

```
  <div *ngFor="let detail of details"  class = "col-sm-12">
    <div class="pic col-sm-1">
    <img  height="60" width="60" [src]='detail.image'>                 
 </div>
  <div class = "col-sm-6">
  <a><div class = "fname col-sm-12">
    {{detail.firstname}}
 </div></a>
  <div class ="phone col-sm-12">
    {{detail.address}}
 </div>
 </div>
   <button  (click)='send(button,detail.profile_id)' #button>{{req}}</button>
   <hr class= "col-xs-12"></div>
```

I want  to  change  the  button  properties  according to  certain conditions,as  follows

```
ngOnInit(){

this._service.getList()
.subscribe(
      response => {
         this.details = response;
          this.details.forEach((name,index)=>{
          if(this.details[index].approved == null){
            button.innerHTML = "Add frnd";
            button.disabled = true; 
          }
          if(this.details[index].approved == 1){
             button.disabled = true;

         }
          if(this.details[index].status == 1){
              button.innerHTML = "Pending";
          }

          });
      }
  }
```

I cannot  use  the  function  here since  it  is   reserved  for  other property,can  any  one  suggest  me  help  regarding  this.........

Comment: Okay. Are you using `ngFor` in template?

Comment: Wait, is there only single button you are dealing with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button  (click)='send(button,detail.profile_id)' [disabled]="isDisabled">{{req}} {{innerHTML}}</button>
```

in Component,

```
{
 isDisabled:boolean:false;
 innerHTML:string='';

this._service.getList().subscribe((response) => {
      this.details = response;
      this.details.forEach((detail)=>{   //<----you are iterating through each object of this.details list.

      if(detail.approved == null){       //<----please note that I changed each if condition with respect to forEach

        //button.innerHTML = "Add frnd";
        //button.disabled = true; 

        this.innerHTML="Add frnd";
        this.isDisabled=true;
      }
      if(detail.approved == 1){
         //button.disabled = true;

          this.isDisabled=true;

     }
      if(detail.status == 1){
          //button.innerHTML = "Pending";

          this.innerHTML="pending";
      }

      });
  }
```

}

Comment: Thanks a lot micronyks'